# How to find least number of moves to swap adjacent colored tiles on 2D grid so that no colors are adjacent?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, a-star

> Sam recently hired a tile installer to tile a kitchen floor. The floor was supposed to be very colorful with no two adjacent tiles having the same color. Unfortunately, the installer failed to ensure adjacent tiles have different colors. The mortar is still wet, but it is difficult to lift just one tile at a time, so the installer is limited to swapping adjacent tiles. The question is how to exchange adjacent tiles in as few moves as possible so that the floor meets the criteria that no two adjacent tiles have the same color.
>
> A sample input is
>
> ```
> RGR
> RPC
> GRB
> YPG
> ```
>
> Representing the tiles on a three by four floor where R is a red tile, G is green, B is blue, C is cyan, P is purple, and Y is yellow. In general, the input will be a series of lines of R, G, B, C, P, and Y. Each line will have the same length
> and **there will be a maximum of 15 lines with 15 characters in each line**. The output is to be an integer representing the number of swaps of adjacent tiles. For this problem, “adjacent” means touching and in the same row or column; for example, the only two tiles are adjacent to the yellow tile in the lower left corner of the above floor: the green tile at the start of the third row and the purple tile in the middle of the fourth row. The output for the above floor will be 2 since the red tile at the start of row 2 can be swapped with the green tile at the start of row three, and then the red tile in middle of row 3 can be swapped with the blue tile at the end.
>
> This gives the arrangement
>
> ```
> RGR
> GPC
> RBR
> YPG
> ```
>
> Other fixes are possible such as exchanging the first two tiles on row 2 to get PRC and then exchanging the middle tiles in rows 3 and 4. Your program does not print the resulting floor arrangement, just the minimum number of tile swaps that must take place.
>
> Sometimes it is not possible to fix a floor:
>
> ```
> GGYGP
> CGGRG
> ```
>
> This isn’t possible to tile because there are 6 Gs and a floor this size can fit only 5 without two being adjacent. In cases where there is no solution, the output is to be
> **not possible**

I honestly don't know where to begin.

It doesn't seem like there is any elegant way to approach this, it doesn't seem to involve dynamic programming since there don't appear to be any repeatable sub-parts, and brute force entirely seems out of the question since the grid can be 15 x 15 in size, which would result in a ridiculous time and/or space complexity.

Comment: You can approach this as a graph problem (a tile arrangement is a vertex, a swap is an edge). Dijkstra's algorithm will find you a shortest path. The worst-case complexity is probably not good though.